# PRE_SUBMIT & SUBMIT form events are not working for login form in symfony 5.4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have created a form extension for the `SecurityLoginType`.

The `FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA` is working well and I am able to add a custom field. However, the other events `FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT` and `FormEvents::SUBMIT` are not working. Am I missing something?

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Form\Extension;


// use Sylius\Bundle\UserBundle\Form\Type\UserLoginType;
use Sylius\Bundle\UiBundle\Form\Type\SecurityLoginType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
// use Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeExtensionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\FlashBagInterface;

final class SecurityLoginTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{

    public function __construct(private ParameterBagInterface $params, private RequestStack $requestStack, private FlashBagInterface $flashBag)
    {
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @param array<mixed> $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, [$this, 'onPreSetData'])
        ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, [$this, 'onPreSubmit'])
        ->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, [$this, 'onSubmit']);
    }
    
    public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event): void
    {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $form->add('customPlainPassword', HiddenType::class, [
            'required' => true,
            'label' => '',
            ]);
            
    }
    
    public function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event): void
    {
        // $form = $event->getForm();
        // 
        // echo ' this is on submitting the login form...';
        echo 'this is from presubmit';
        dd($event);
        exit();
        
    }
    
    public function onSubmit(FormEvent $event): void
    {
        echo 'on submit event';
        dd($event);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getExtendedTypes(): iterable
    {
        return [SecurityLoginType::class];
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**
I ended up customizing the `security.login.failure` when authentication fails and `security.interactive_login` when authentication is successful

```
 app.security.interactive_login:
        class: App\EventListener\LoginListener
        arguments:
            - '@router'
            - '@sylius.context.channel'
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: interactiveLogin }
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.login.failure', method: interactiveLoginFailed}
```

Comment: Both methods are defined fine here. Something is wrong from the rendering side. Are you sure this form is called when your form submit?

Comment: only `onPreSetData` function is called but not the other events

Comment: Everything is fine here. Only I can guess this rendering option!
`$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, [$this, 'onPreSetData']);
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, [$this, 'onPreSubmit']);
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, [$this, 'onSubmit']);`
Can you please try line-by-line declaration?

Comment: Tried that as well, didn't work.

Comment: POST /login is handled by Symfony's authentication system.  The form never gets involved.

Comment: @Cerad , @Manas said `FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA` is working well.

Comment: @BhavinNakrani only `PRE_SET_DATA` is working for login. I ended up using the `onAuthenticationFailure` handler for processing my logic upon a failed authentication and `interactiveLogin` upon a successful authentication